# Why is np.dtype(None) = float?

Tags: numpy

Why is this the default behavior of numpy?

```
In [5]: np.dtype(None)
Out[5]: dtype('float64')
```

I was hoping to use `np.issubdtype(None,float)` for some type-checking involving return types for images (PIL likes 0-255 images, `skimage` likes `[0,1)` images), but that does not work.  I'd be interested in a clean-looking workaround, but I'll be satisfied with an answer to the main question.

Comment: Could you explain a little more why you would want to use `None` in the first place as one of the arguments to `np.issubdtype`?

Comment: something like this: `def f(x,dtype=None): if np.issubdtype(dtype,float): return convert_to_float(x) else: return x`

Comment: Is `dtype` here just `x.dtype`? If it is, just use it and you won't have to worry about a default. Also, do you mean `if not np.issubdtype(. . )`?

Comment: No, `dtype` should be a keyword in this context.  And, `not` doesn't matter, I was actually going to have a few cases for different dtypes.  Normally, you'd want to duck-type, but with RGB images, you actually need different numerical scaling depending on the data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a special case where `None` is converted to the default dtype. See:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2190